# How to dynamically change component's style?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To simplify the code, lets say I have to components (buttons). A parent and a child. When the parent is clicked, it sends property (number) to the child. This number helps select a specific color inside an array. Then, when I click on the child button, its color changes to the selected color. And that's where my problem is. I don't know how to update the component with the new color.

```
var arrayOfColors = ["#cd6155", "#af7ac5", "#5499c7", "#48c9b0", "#58d68d", "#f5b041", "#dc7633", "#EAECEE",
                 "#c0392b", "#9b59b6", "#2980b9", "#1abc9c", "#2ecc71", "#f39c12", "#d35400", "#D5D8DC",
                 "#a93226", "#884ea0", "#2471a3", "#17a589", "#28b463", "#d68910", "#ba4a00", "#ABB2B9",
                 "#922b21", "#76448a", "#1f618d", "#148f77", "#239b56", "#b9770e", "#a04000", "#808B96",
                 "#7b241c", "#633974", "#1a5276", "#117864", "#1d8348", "#9c640c", "#873600", "#566573",
                 "#641e16", "#512e5f", "#154360", "#0e6251", "#186a3b", "#7e5109", "#6e2c00", "#2C3E50"];

var color = null; //Initial global value that changes to a number selected from the parent component
```

Child component

```
class Square extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: null};
    }
    handleClick(){
        this.setState({value: color, });
        var myStyle = {background: "pink"};
        myStyle.background  = arrayOfColors[this.props.value];
        boardColor = myStyle;

        ...................................................
        This is where the update should happen (I suppose).
        The button with style={boardColor}
        ...................................................
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <button  className="square"  onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
          {this.state.value}
        </button>
      );
    }
}
```

I've see somewhere it was possible to change a component's color by changing its name. And then, in a `Css` file, have a different style for each name. The change occurs between two colors. I don't think that solution is adapted to my problem since I have more than 40 different colors

Comment: You have a few options. Most straightforward (but not the most sophisticated and/or performant) would be done through inline `style` attribute. The other one is that you can leverage one of the css-in-js libraries such as [`styled-components`](https://www.styled-components.com/).

Comment: How do you re-render the component with the new "inline style" ?

Comment: I think you've figured it out by now through the accepted answer -- the attribute value change would trigger a re-render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <title>Example</title>
 </head>

 <body>
    <div id="app">
    </div> 
    <script type="text/babel">
        const SquareParent = () => {
          return <Square parentColorNumber={11}/>
        }
        
        const arrayOfColors = ["#cd6155", "#af7ac5", "#5499c7", "#48c9b0", "#58d68d", "#f5b041", "#dc7633", "#EAECEE",
                 "#c0392b", "#9b59b6", "#2980b9", "#1abc9c", "#2ecc71", "#f39c12", "#d35400", "#D5D8DC",
                 "#a93226", "#884ea0", "#2471a3", "#17a589", "#28b463", "#d68910", "#ba4a00", "#ABB2B9",
                 "#922b21", "#76448a", "#1f618d", "#148f77", "#239b56", "#b9770e", "#a04000", "#808B96",
                 "#7b241c", "#633974", "#1a5276", "#117864", "#1d8348", "#9c640c", "#873600", "#566573",
                 "#641e16", "#512e5f", "#154360", "#0e6251", "#186a3b", "#7e5109", "#6e2c00", "#2C3E50"];

        class Square extends React.Component {
            constructor(props){
                super(props);
                this.state = { backgroundColor: null };
            }

            handleClick = () => {
                const backgroundColor = arrayOfColors[this.props.parentColorNumber - 1];
                this.setState({ backgroundColor });
            }

            render() {
              const { backgroundColor } = this.state;
              return (
                <div>
                  <button className="square" style={{ backgroundColor }} onClick={ () => this.handleClick() }>
                    Current color - {this.state.backgroundColor || 'none'}
                  </button>
                </div>
              );
            }
        }
        ReactDOM.render(<SquareParent/>, document.getElementById('app'))
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I added as a parentColorNumber: 11. You can change it as you want.
You have a parent component that sends the data to it's child component.

Comment: It works now. Except for  `style={{ backgroundColor }}`. I had to change to `style={{ background: backgroundColor }}`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Square extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: null,backgroundColor:null};
    }
    handleClick(){
        this.setState({value: color, });
        var  bg = arrayOfColors[this.props.value];
       this.setState({backgroundColor:bg});

    }
    render() {
      const { backgroundColor } = this.state;
      return (
        <button  className="square" style={{backgroundColor}}  onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
          {this.state.value}
        </button>
      );
    }
}
```